# Image in material shrunk after render

Tags: rendering, materials

I'm modeling a iMac. I did UV mapping for the in screen image and applied image texture to the screen. Everything looks fine on viewport. But when I render the image in the texture shrunk.

[image: Image in material shrunk after render]

I have tried, removing the edges and adding them back in. I have tried creating new texture. Adding new image. Moving the mesh to a clean file. Nothing works.

Comment: My guess is you have a subdivision surface modifier tuned down/off in preview, bur on in render. If this is the case, you can fix the image size by adding supporting geometry to the screen area - both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Definitely an issue with subdivision surface. You need to add another loop around the image part of the screen, or you need to mark the edges as sharp.

Answer (score 1):

Yup. It was the subdivision modifier. Just needed remove it, or add in crease around the edge of the image. Thanks, problem solved.